# Symfony 3.3 Twig error template extends base.html.twig not working

Tags: symfony, templates, twig, symfony-3.3, symfony3.x

In Symfony 3.3 I defined an error-template in

```
../app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error404.html.twig
```

In that template I extend a base-template like

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
```

I get this error

```
The merge filter only works with arrays or "Traversable", got "NULL" as first argument.
```

I tried

```
{% extends ':base.html.twig' %}
```

too, resulting in the following error

```
Unable to find template ":base.html.twig" (looked into: ..\Path\to\App\app/Resources/views, ..)
```

Notice that the path is correct but twig(?) does not find the template.

I can not find a way to fix this...
Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Does the base template work with other templates?  Seems like the problem lies in your 404 template.  Does it use the merge filter?

Comment: @Cerad Yeah, the base template works with other templates - the problem occured only when trying to use it in error-templates. I can not find any explizit merge-function call. If I remove to extend the base template the error template works fine. If I copy the contents from base into the error template then it fails at another "extends" call which exists inside base.html.twig. So for any reason the extends-functionality seems to be the cause here.

Comment: Strange.  Maybe you could make a gist will all the involved templates and post a link.  Or maybe try rendering your 404 template from a regular controller?  Though I really don't think it would make a difference.

Comment: @Cerad When trying to prepare the templates for a gist I found that I have to edit my question a bit as for when I call the base template with ":" at the beginning ({% extends ':base.html.twig' %}) the error changes to Unable to find template ":base.html.twig" (looked into: ..\Path\to\App\app/Resources/views, ..) - notice that the path is correct. So twig (?) seems to look for the right template at the right location but does not find it anyways? Why is that?

Comment: Why would you put a colon as a prefix?  There is an older style Bundle:Dir:Name format but just using a single colon?  bin/console debug: twig will list the directories searched for templates but I think you are going down the wrong road.  The mystery is where the merge is coming from.

Comment: @Cerad Y i just read about that old convention too. I seem to be misled here. What is it what I am looking for regarding this merge issue?

Comment: @Cerad I found the merge that is causing the issue (sorry for being blind at this). In an included template there exists this line (in between the arrows) ----> <li><a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'en'})) }}">{{ 'English'|trans() }}</a></li> <---- and this line fails...

Comment: Progress.  Might want to update your question again as comments do not format well.  Should be easy enough to figure out why _route_params is not returning an array.

Comment: @Cerad Yep. True. Problem easily solved. The issue was not related to extends in any way - I just didn't see the implications from that other include. Thanks for your help though - it led me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I was misled by the error message.
The issue came from another included template which used a null variable and tried to merge it with something else.
So the actual problem was not related to any call of "extends".